# Need to send email on database insert

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, email

This question might look similar to existing one's but is really different.

I have a scenario where I have to send emails to different users while inserting data into MySQL DB. The logical part has been completed using Java. This is reading very huge data from via CSV files on file server and after processing those data, inserting into DB.

Now my need is to send email to different users on each insert operation.

The data is quite very heavy so I think using triggers would not be a good idea.

Can you please help me to get a better solution?

I do also have php app connectivity with this database.

Comment: why you can't send emails on java insert method ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should try php library like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer),  [PEAR Mail](https://github.com/pear/Mail), [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), etc as you should note that php's mail function is inherently not optimized at all.